# Is there a way to RESIZE an Image directly in URL using FIREBASE?

Tags: firebase, react-native, image-resizing

I want to crop the Size of an Image directly in the url
I uploaded the images in FireBase and I'm willing to know if they offer this feature.

Any advice and suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you please explain your requirement in detail ?

Comment: I uploaded an image of 900 x 1200 inside Firebase Server, I want a service that crops the image directly for example at 200x200 so that I can download the cropped image directly from the web/server instead of cropping it from the client-side, thanks in advance.

Comment: You will find in the Cloud Functions samples several samples that convert images with [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php). You could adapt them to use the resize function of ImageMagick, see https://imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/. The Cloud Functions samples are https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/convert-images/functions/index.js, https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/exif-images/functions/index.js and https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/generate-thumbnail/functions/index.js

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not a product feature offered by Firebase or Google Cloud products.

Answer (score 0):

Well, firebase does not provide any method to compress or crop images while uploading images. You can crop images before uploading to firebase using:
https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker

Answer (score 0):

If you know what sizes you want (maybe your app use predefined image sizes depending on the platform / screen width), you can use [this firebase extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/storage-resize-images) (blaze plan).

When you upload an image on storage, it creates multiple resizes on your bucket.

Could be useful depending on your needs.

**Edit**

For my apps, I wrote a cloud function to upload images on my bucket (React-native expo)

I post my base64 image on an http cloud function and use [sharp](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-resize) to resize it.

Then I save my image on my bucket and store its url on firestore (on a document related to this image, a product in my case)